# Access denied, despite correct permissions

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, file-permissions

I tried using `robocopy` to mirror a folder to a new location; a few files and folders failed with "Access Denied," although I was using an user in the local admin group, which *does* have access to these files. (I double checked in the security tab.) These permissions (and adding my user to the admin group) were set up long ago, so it's not a matter of login out and back in.

At first, I thought this was because another process had the file open with a lock; but I tested, and that gives a different error message.

To rule out the possibility of broken permissions, I re-ran the `robocopy` command as the SYSTEM user. However, this failed with the same error! For these files, there are two entries listed in the Security tab: the local Administrators group, and the SYSTEM user. Both have full control. How could either user fail to have access?

Comment: Try with the '/B' or '/ZB' flags